# python tuple to dict

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

For the tuple, `t = ((1, 'a'),(2, 'b'))`
`dict(t)` returns `{1: 'a', 2: 'b'}`

Is there a good way to get `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}` (keys and vals swapped)?

Ultimately, I want to be able to return `1` given `'a'` or `2` given `'b'`, perhaps converting to a dict is not the best way.

Answer (score 357, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> t = ((1, 'a'),(2, 'b'))
>>> dict((y, x) for x, y in t)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: +1 Beautiful!, I had to try it with zip  `dict(zip(*zip(*t)[::-1]))`.  This is slower, uglier and using way more memory..likely 3x.

Comment: @kevpie The wonderful thing about Python is that there are a hundred ways to express how to do something, each just as interesting as the next.

Comment: Great, if what you have a is a triple you can do: `dict((x, y) for x, y, z in t)` or `dict((x, (y, z)) for x, y, z in t)` to get the second and third values as a tuple.

Comment: Also possible with a dict literal instead of a dict constructor: `{y: x for x, y in t}`

Comment: @bjd2385 Actually, this is a bit of a contradiction to clause 13 of PEP 20 (`import this`) ... All the same, it's true what you're saying.

Answer (score 93):

A slightly simpler method:

```
>>> t = ((1, 'a'),(2, 'b'))
>>> dict(map(reversed, t))
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: what makes this faster ?

Comment: The map and dict functions are implement in C and are much faster than any python version

Comment: I like this for having the `reverse` explicitely spelled out.

Comment: @maazza: in general, performance tests suggest that (in the C implementation at least) `map` is faster than a comprehension when the thing being mapped is another built-in function (like `reversed`); in most other cases, the opposite is true. But it's better to profile than guess :)

Comment: Nice! However, to my preference, the `for` expression looks slightly more obvious.

Answer (score 53):

Even more concise if you are on python 2.7:

```
>>> t = ((1,'a'),(2,'b'))
>>> {y:x for x,y in t}
{'a':1, 'b':2}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
>>> dict([('hi','goodbye')])
{'hi': 'goodbye'}
```

Or:

```
>>> [ dict([i]) for i in (('CSCO', 21.14), ('CSCO', 21.14), ('CSCO', 21.14), ('CSCO', 21.14)) ]
[{'CSCO': 21.14}, {'CSCO': 21.14}, {'CSCO': 21.14}, {'CSCO': 21.14}]
```

Comment: You misunderstood the question - the point is how to swap keys and values. This simple conversion is already stated in the question itself.

Answer (score 7):

If there are multiple values for the same key, the following code will append those values to a list corresponding to their key,

```
d = dict()
for x,y in t:
    if(d.has_key(y)):
        d[y].append(x)
    else:
        d[y] = [x]
```

Comment: Removed dict.has_key() – use the in operator instead.

Comment: d = dict()

##
for x,y in t:
    d.setdefault(x,[]).append(y)

Answer (score 3):

Here are couple ways of doing it:

```
>>> t = ((1, 'a'), (2, 'b'))

>>> # using reversed function
>>> dict(reversed(i) for i in t)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}

>>> # using slice operator
>>> dict(i[::-1] for i in t)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score -2):

With Python 3.6 and above, it's a function:

```
mydict=myty._asdict()
```