# Openstack output in json format

Tags: json, python-2.7, novaclient

I am using novaclient to get the details from Openstack. i am able to retrieve the information, however i want to convert it into json format. i am using "to_dic()" but it;s throwing "Attribute" error on "server_details = server_id_name.to_dict()", not sure why.

```
AttributeError: "'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_dict'"
```

Code is given below,

```
from novaclient import client as novaclient
import json

nova = novaclient.Client(version='2.0',username='xxxx',api_key='xxxx',project_id='xxxx',auth_url='http://192.168.12.3:5000/v2.0/',insecure='True')

server_details = dict()
server = nova.servers.list()
for server in nova.servers.list():
    print server.id, server.name
    server_id_name = server.id, server.name
    server_details = server_id_name.to_dict()
    for network in server.networks.items():
        print network
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a error in your python code.
you should use

```
server_details[server.id] = server.name
```

to replace your code

```
server_id_name = server.id, server.name
server_details = server_id_name.to_dict()
```

BTW, you should learn more about python. If you want to change a tuple to a dict, you should see [python-tuple-to-dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783530/python-tuple-to-dict)

Comment: Thanks and agreed, i am new to the python!