# How to convert tuple of arrays to a dict?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have the following tuple:

```
t = (array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=uint8), array([1568726,  346469,  589708,   91961]))
```

that I'd need to convert to a dict as follows:

```
dict = {0: 1568726, 1: 346469, 2: 589708, 3: 91961}
```

I'm trying with

```
d = dict((x, y) for x, y in t)
```

but it's not resolving the nesting of the tuple I have. Any suggestions?

[Another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783530) appears to be similar, but is not: its main issue is re transposing the dict elements, while this question focuses on how to join 2 arrays within a tuple into a dict.

Comment: `d = dict(zip(*t))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python tuple to dict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783530/python-tuple-to-dict)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions#zip) (to create key-value pairs) and [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dict) (to convert the pairs to a dictionary):

```
>>> from numpy import array, uint8
>>> t = (array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=uint8),
         array([1568726,  346469,  589708,   91961]))
>>> dict(zip(*t))
{0: 1568726, 1: 346469, 2: 589708, 3: 91961}
```