# Pythonic way to transform list of pairs to dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

I have a List of pairs like this:

```
[
    {'Name': 'first_name', 'Value': 'Joe'},
    {'Name': 'last_name', 'Value': 'Smith'},
    {'Name': 'gender', 'Value': 'male'}
]
```

I want to transform it into a Dict like this:

```
{
    'first_name': 'Joe',
    'last_name': 'Smith',
    'gender': 'male'
}
```

I am currently using a simple loop to accomplish this now but I know there is a more Pythonic way to do it. Thoughts?

-Tony

Comment: Perhaps `{d['Name'] : d['Value'] for d in dct}`

Comment: Check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783530/python-tuple-to-dict

Answer (score 2):

It was easier than I expected:

```
{pair['Name']:pair['Value'] for pair in source_list}
```

This uses a feature of Python called a Dict comprehension.

Comment: Its `pair["Name"]` not `pair["Key"]`

Comment: Isn't this called a `dict comprehension` not a `map comprehension`? See pep 274

Comment: @KevInski You are correct. Updated my post to reflect this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate a dict with the generator output of the `values()` method on each dict in the list:

```
dict(d.values() for d in l)
```

Comment: This requires the values be enumerated in a specific order. That is an invalid assumption. The items returned by the `values()` method will be in a random order prior to python 3.7. And even in python 3.7 the order depends on the order in which the keys were inserted.