# How can I create a dictionary from multiple tuples?

Tags: python

I have a bunch of tuples:

```
Stadt = ("Berlin", "Santiago", "Madrid", "Dallas", "Mexico")
Befolkerung = (3.8, 5.6, 6.6, 1.34, 8.86)
Land = ("Deutschland", "Chile", "Spanien", "Vereinigte Staaten", "Mexico")
Breitengrad = (1,2,3,4,5)
Langengrad = (2,4,6,8,10)
```

I would like to create a dictionary from these with `Stadt` as keys and the rest of the tuples as values. How would you go about this?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783530/python-tuple-to-dict

Comment: Use the zip() function with the lists have the same size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `zip` with `dict`

**Ex:**

```
Stadt = ("Berlin", "Santiago", "Madrid", "Dallas", "Mexico")
Befolkerung = (3.8, 5.6, 6.6, 1.34, 8.86)
Land = ("Deutschland", "Chile", "Spanien", "Vereinigte Staaten", "Mexico")
Breitengrad = (1,2,3,4,5)
Langengrad = (2,4,6,8,10)

print(dict(zip(Stadt, zip(Befolkerung, Land, Breitengrad, Langengrad))))
```

**Output:**

```
{'Berlin': (3.8, 'Deutschland', 1, 2),
 'Dallas': (1.34, 'Vereinigte Staaten', 4, 8),
 'Madrid': (6.6, 'Spanien', 3, 6),
 'Mexico': (8.86, 'Mexico', 5, 10),
 'Santiago': (5.6, 'Chile', 2, 4)}
```

Answer (score 4):

```py
dict(zip(Stadt, zip(Befolkerung, Land, Breitengrad, Langengrad)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your exact requirement regarding keys:

Following code has multiple keys: Stadt, Befolkerung, Land, Breitengrad, Langengrad

```
dictionary={
    'Stadt':Stadt,
    'Befolkerung':Befolkerung,
    'Land':Land,
    'Breitengrad':Breitengrad,
    'Langengrad':Langengrad
} 
print(dictionary)
```

**output:**

```
{
 'Stadt': ('Berlin', 'Santiago', 'Madrid', 'Dallas', 'Mexico'),
 'Befolkerung': (3.8, 5.6, 6.6, 1.34, 8.86),
 'Land': ('Deutschland', 'Chile', 'Spanien', 'Vereinigte Staaten', 'Mexico'),
 'Breitengrad': (1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
 'Langengrad': (2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
yourdict = {}
Stadt = ("Berlin", "Santiago", "Madrid", "Dallas", "Mexico")
Befolkerung = (3.8, 5.6, 6.6, 1.34, 8.86)
Land = ("Deutschland", "Chile", "Spanien", "Vereinigte Staaten", "Mexico")
Breitengrad = (1,2,3,4,5)
Langengrad = (2,4,6,8,10)
for key in list(locals().keys()):
    if(not key.startswith('__')):
        yourdict[key] = locals()[key]
print(yourdict)
```